# Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: tooManyRetries

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft.Graph 3.8.0 .net nuget package.
And sometimes I have such error

*Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: tooManyRetries 

Message: More than 3 retries encountered while sending the request.


at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at Microsoft.Graph.MessageDeltaRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)*

As I understand it is standard Microsofy.Graph retry handler. But how can I identify the original exception? Inner exception in ServiceException is empty

Answer (score 0):

I've just removed the default retry handler and now have the original exception.
it is **Code: ApplicationThrottled Message: Application is over its MailboxConcurrency limit.**

```
var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers(provider);

// Remove a default handler
var retryHandler = handlers.Where(h => h is RetryHandler).FirstOrDefault();
handlers.Remove(retryHandler);


var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);
```